# How to load a list of images in Android programming

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

```
public class Const {
   public static int[] image = {R.drawable.apple, R.drawable.chicken, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.tiger, R.drawable.orange};
}

public void changePic(int count){
    int num = Const.image[count];
    mCurrentStagePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    if(mCurrentStagePic !=null){
        mCurrentStagePic.setImageResource(num);
    }   
}
```

I want to change my loading pictures when pass a level and load the next picture. But every time run this code, project then crashed.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: when do you call the `changePic` function post it here

Comment: @Joseph Malicke @ Rod_Algonquin Thanks a lot, I've solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you... Use `GridView` for that.

`ImageAdapter.java`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {
      imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }

      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
   }

   // Keep all Images in array
   public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
      R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
      R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
      R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
      R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
   };
}
```

in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

And your `MainActivity.java` should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
      gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: I just removed the code snippets from your post. They are only meant for `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript`. To add any other code, indent it with 4 spaces.